# Proper use of polymorphic association for reports

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Category` model that `has_many` `Link` and `Text` posts, and those posts have many `Report`s.

How should I best set up my models/schema to retrieve all reports for the category by using `@category.reports`? I based this on the example in the docs:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :link_posts, class_name: "Link"
  has_many :text_posts, class_name: "Text"
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :reports, as: :reportable
end

class Text < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :reports, as: :reportable
end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reportable, polymorphic: true
end
```

If I do something like that I would have to use a hacky method to retrieve them:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  def reports
    reports = []

    reports << Report.where(reportable: self.link_posts.to_a)
    reports << Report.where(reportable: self.text_posts.to_a)

    reports
  end
end
```

What's the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the category on the report -- that way you can look all of them up based on the `Category`, `Link` or `Text`. There is no real harm in associating many items together.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :link_posts, class_name: "Link"
  has_many :text_posts, class_name: "Text"
  has_many :reports, as: :reportable
end

class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :reports, as: :reportable
end

class Text < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :reports, as: :reportable
end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :reportable, polymorphic: true
end
```